# What is the fastest way to retrieve header names from excel files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a big size excel files that I'm organizing the column names into a unique list.
The code below works, but it takes ~9 minutes!
Does anyone have suggestions for speeding it up?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
get_col = list(pd.read_excel("E:\DATA\dbo.xlsx",nrows=1, engine='openpyxl').columns)
print(get_col)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas to extract just the column names of a large excel file is very inefficient.
You can use openpyxl for this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("E:\DATA\dbo.xlsx", read_only=True)

columns = {}

for sheet in worksheets:
    for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, values_only=True):
        columns = value
```

Assuming you only have one sheet, you will get a tuple of column names here.

Comment: OP is already using `openpyxl` as engine for `pd.read_excel()` and I think this doesn't solve the fact that OP still needs to load the full file for it to then access it and then loop through it. (It might still be a bit faster than OPs original code)

Comment: `columns = value` looks like a typo.

Comment: Celius, there's nothing to suggest that the whole file needs loading and, even if this is required, this answer is **definitely** the way to go, because it minimises the amount of memory required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want faster reading, then I suggest you use other type files. Excel, while convenient and fast are binary files, therefore for pandas to be able to read it and correctly parse it must use the full file. Using `nrows` or `skipfooter` to work with less data with only happen **after** the full data is loaded and therefore shouldn't really affect the waiting time. On the opposite, when working with a `.csv()` file, given its type and that there is no significant metadata, you can just extract the first rows of it as an interable using the `chunksize` parameter in [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Other than that, using `list()` with a dataframe as value, returns a list of the columns already. So my only suggestion for the code you use is:

```
get_col = list(pd.read_excel("E:\DATA\dbo.xlsx",nrows=1, engine='openpyxl'))
```

The stronger suggestion is to change datatype if you specifically want to address this issue.